# fetching parameter in a link php codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, get

Say I have this url

```
http://localhost/newtkt/index.php/welcome/gettkt/PfIfiETYXzUpYRJf6RPvyncN4PgdN3
```

and a controller function

```
public function gettkt()
{
  //mydata
}
```

how can i retrieve the parameter `PfIfiETYXzUpYRJf6RPvyncN4PgdN3` that comes with the url and make it a variable in my controller function `gettkt()` so that i can use the parameter within the function like `gettkt(thisparameter)`. I hope I've structured my question in the best way possible. thank you.

Comment: try `$this->request->param` or use `$this->input->get()` or `$this->uri->segment('3');` where 3 is for 3rd param

Comment: i get error `Undefined property: Welcome::$request`

Comment: use  `$this->input->get()` or `$this->uri->segment('3');` where `3` is for `3rd` param

Comment: Yeah yeah its working now with `$this->uri->segment('3');`

Comment: Thanks alot @urfusion

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things

**Method 01**

```
public function gettkt($parm)
{
    echo $parm; # Prints PfIfiETYXzUpYRJf6RPvyncN4PgdN3
}
```

**Method 02**

Use [URI Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html) in CodeIgniter

```
$parm = $this->uri->segment(n); # Number point your parameter 
$parm = $this->uri->segment(3); # Prints PfIfiETYXzUpYRJf6RPvyncN4PgdN3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$this->uri->segment('3'); //where 3 is for 3rd param
```

for more information visit [URI](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html)